# Position on Offer Letter is different

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I went through 3 phases of interview. During my last technical interview prior to the HR interview, the head of the department told me that he will be assigning me position X in the company if selected.

Once, I cleared my HR interview, HR sent me a mail stating my salary and my position. The position mentioned there was Y(lower) than X which was told to me by the department head. I had a day to accept the mail so I accepted with a note stating that I was told that I will be getting position X.

Today I got the final offer letter which mentions Y as my position which is lower. I have been given a weeks time to accept it. I can't afford to miss this job. Please advice on how should I proceed and how can I get my initially awarded position X back. I am into pool of confusions on whether it will be unprofessional of me, whether it will affect them and they disqualify me. (I am 3+ Years Experienced professional)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Called up the HR and they said, according to the number of years of experience, the position granted will be Y. I didn't investigated any further. Accepted and moved on! Thanks all.

Comment: If you truly cannot afford to miss the job, you might have to accept it, provided you feel it its worth doing so.  Only you can decide if that is the case.  It is much easier to get a job, with a job, then without a job.

Comment: This is off topic because it is about a specific agreement between you and your prospective employer.  They have made an offer to you your choice to accept or not is up to you.  How they will respond to anything counter is not something we can help with.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings agreed, this is misleadingly starting off as a general question just to turn into a personal advice request right at the end

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Please advice on how should I proceed and how can I get my initially
>   awarded position X back.

You made a mistake "accepting" the earlier mail, even with adding your noew. Now is your only chance to correct that mistake.

**Immediately call whoever sent the offer letter. Explain that you are confused, since you thought this was for position X, but the current offer letter mentions only position Y.**

Then listen.

You'll find out quickly which position they are actually offering you, whether they made a mistake in their offers, or not. And then be ready to either accept whatever is being offered or decline and move on.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that if they state to "just sign this offer letter and we'll get you a new one when we can." don't. You don't have to be unprofessional about it, just say "I feel uncomfortable signing something that isn't correct. I'd really like to hold off until I receive the correct paperwork."

Comment: @Joe - Those were quite impressive lines. Well, about making "mistake" I agree I made it. But, it was an informal mail where I clearly accepted it informally with a "note" stating about the promised position. Wasn't that enough considering the employer is one of the biggest tech giants to understand what I mean? HR's are up-to the mark when it comes to hiring. Then how come this simple loss of ethic? All this made me think. Else, I don't care about position. I love to work. Its just about what I should have seen but didn't.

Comment: @zfrisch Yes, makes sense. But, its difficult for me to say it without hesitation. When I say, I can't afford, I really mean it. I just can't afford to lose the opportunity.

Comment: @BSC First step is to clarify (preferably on the telephone) as mentioned here. If you truly can't afford to lose the opportunity, then you'd best be prepared to accept the "lower" position, but not without first listening to their explanation of the mixup.

Comment: This sort of bait and switch is all too common.  The advertisement and interview is initially for X position, which then is closed or someone else is chosen but since we have you in lets offer you this snowball position and see if we can get you for a bargain.

Answer (score 2):

> The position mentioned there was Y(lower) than X which was told to me by the department head.

Be extremely weary when a formal offer and the non-binding verbal offer are significantly different.  This could be a **bait-and-switch** tactic used by an unscrupulous company to get people to work for less money.

You've verbally agreed to a certain position at a certain salary, and now the company isn't honoring their promise.  If they are treating you this way, they are also likely treating all their other employees and customers this way.  If you take this position, **this will likely be the first in a long line of broken promises.**

Comment: 1. The company is one big tech-giant. 2. Salary is not an issue. 3. I don't care about the position much, but yes, if they said X, I should have got X. That's the only concern I have. Just don't have to sound unpro or greedy while asking for it. The last option is to drop the idea and move on. Thanks though.

Comment: @BSC: You did indicate that job Y is lower. Now, salary is not an issue?

Comment: I'm really confused.  If salary isn't the issue what is?  If you don't care about the position much why are you obsessing over it?  If you don't care much for the job, don't take it.  What is the real issue that made you post?

Answer (score 2):

Is the salary lower, or just the title? The same salary and a lower title could be to your advantage: Now you can get promoted from lower-job to higher-job, which should then come with a pay raise.

If the salary is lower, or if the issue is not a title but rather the nature of the job -- like you were expecting "sales manager" and instead they're now offering "salt mine worker" -- before you take any further steps you should decide in your own mind, If the lower title is all they are prepared to offer me, is that good enough or will I turn them down? Don't call them until you have made this decision, because if they say, "no, this is it, will you take this job or not", you don't want to be in a position where you have to make a snap decision.

Following up on Sevensevens answer: You should consider whether this is a mistake, a technicality, or some sort of trick. If the interviewer told me they were prepared to offer me a position as Widget Maker Level 12 and then the HR department says no, the position is Widget Maker Level 11, it might well be that the interviewer was confused about details. But if I was sold on a job as Regional Manager and given big promises about how I'd be running the entire region with big pay and bonuses and all, and then they came back and said, oh, we meant that you'd be the junior deputy assistant to the regional manager, with the possibility that maybe someday you could become regional manager, I'd be concerned. Even if the job offered was acceptable, were they lying to me? And if they lied about this, what else are they lying about, and what else will they lie to me about in the future if I take the job?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a private meeting with the head of the department and discuss this situation. Get an objective plan on how you can achieve that position as soon as possible. Under the circumstances, it would be more genuine of acknowledging the mistake and possibly provide a faster track for promotion.

Accidents and miscommunication can happen, but I feel this company should have honored their word and offered you something if they couldn't give you the position you applied for. Otherwise, this smells like a "bait and switch" tactic.

If they're not able to show you they can keep their word, start looking for a new job as soon as possible. You're young, one quick job hop isn't going to kill your career, but you need to make sure the next job is one worth keeping.